# Update Label text from XML

Tags: iphone

I have an XML will is parsed and then fed to a bunch of Labels.

I am trying to add a live element so that the labels refresh automatically from the XML.

From what I've read this is possible using a tableView and [tableView reloadData] but the design dictates the use of labels. At the moment the labels only get updated on restarting the app, which is not ideal.

Using ViewWillAppear is one option, but want to stick to using lables.

Comment: You'll need to explain a bit better or post some code.  Is there anything wrong with just doing `self.label1.text = foo`?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have some object that manages the parsing of your XML, you'll probably want to give this object a delegate, and create a delegate method like `xmlDataDidUpdate: (id)parser`, when the XML parsing has been completed you can then notify your delegate and update your view accordingly.